# Codeigniter 3.1.7 - Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Helo, Im new to php and CI. I just following ci tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8Ctjz_GsbE_aDCg2HqdM4X046XD5Jrjp), and i got problem in this [part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GND12nVV9CU&index=9&list=PL8Ctjz_GsbE_aDCg2HqdM4X046XD5Jrjp).

Here is my model

```
public $rules_admin = array(
      'name' => array(
        'field' => 'name',
        'rules' => 'trim|required'
      ),
      'email' => array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email'
      ),
      'password' => array(
        'field' => 'password',
        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password_confirm]'
      ),
      'password_confirm' => array(
        'field' => 'password_confirm',
        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password]'
      )
    );
```

This is my controller

```
function edit($id = NULL)
  {
    $id == NULL || $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);

    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password'] .= '|required'; // i have Noticed about this

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    }

    $this->data['subview'] = 'components/admin_edit';
    $this->load->view('components/index', $this->data);
  }

  public function _unique_email($str)
  {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    $user = $this->user_m->get();

    if (count($user)) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('_unique_email', '%s should be unique');
      return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
  }
```

I have loaded model, helper, library.

I also found 2 comments on video that provide solution, i try it but still not working.

What should i do? Thank you.

Comment: any update @dany??

Comment: i remove dot from this `$rules['password'] .= '|required';` the url give me `http://cmsdanul.dev.com/admin/user/edit?name=&email=dany%40dev.com&password=&password_confirm=`

no error displayed, but the validation didn't work

Answer (score 0):

define `$rules` as an array on top of the method

```
$rules = array();
$rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
```

or

```
 $rules[] = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
```

---

No idea with what you trying to archive here `$id || $rules['password'] .= '';`

If you need to push this to array you can use `$rules['password'] = '|required';` (for password)

Answer (score 0):

change

> $id || $rules['password'] .= '|required';

to

> $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';

`$rules['password']` is Array . Use String type `.`  Operator,  return `Notice Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: i do, but validation error message still not working